# Check if a list of numbers is in a certain range?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, range

I try to discretize some numbers, by looking if they are in a given range, and then assign a number based on the range, however the result which I get is not exactly correct.

`mapp` is the a dictionary of which defines ranges, and the values which correspond to the given range.

`lst` is the list of numbers that I want to match against those ranges, and assign identifiers to them

```
mapp = {(0,100): 1, (100,400): 2, (400,800): 3}


lst = [3.5, 5.4, 300.12, 500.78, 600.45, 900.546]


def discretize(mapping_dict, list_of_values):
    print "\n"
    location = []
    for x in sorted(list_of_values):
        for (lower_bound,upper_bound),value in mapping_dict.items():
            if round(x) in range(lower_bound,upper_bound):
                print round(x), "yes", value

                distance = mapping_dict[(lower_bound,upper_bound)]
                location.append((distance))


        else:
            print round(x), "no"

            distance = len(mapping_dict.items())+10
            location.append((distance))

    return location
```

The result which I expect is: `[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 13]` , however that's not what I get.

This is the actual result which I get, which is incorrect:

```
4.0 yes 1
4.0 no         #wrong!
5.0 yes 1
5.0 no         #wrong!
300.0 yes 2
300.0 no         #wrong!
501.0 yes 3
501.0 no         #wrong!
600.0 yes 3
600.0 no         #wrong!
901.0 no         #CORRECT

[1, 13, 1, 13, 2, 13, 3, 13, 3, 13, 13]
```

I get `no` at `4.0` which is not correct, etc, etc.

Where is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: You probably just need to `break` from the loop once you find the right group, otherwise the `else` will always be executed.

Comment: you definitely do not want to create ranges like you are. you simply need to use `lower_bound <= val < upper_bound` or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mapp = {(0,100): 1, (100,400): 2, (400,800): 3}
lst = [3.5, 5.4, 300.12, 500.78, 600.45, 900.546]
result = []
for l in lst:
    for m in mapp:
        if m[0] < l < m[1]:
            result.append(mapp[m])

print result
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3]
```

EDIT:

```
result = []
for l in lst:
    flag=True
    for m in mapp:
        if m[0] < l < m[1]:
            result.append(mapp[m])
            flag = False
            break
    if flag:
        result.append(-1)
print result
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, -1]
```

Comment: thanks, but this solution still does not consider the case for `900.546` @user3

Comment: how do you calculate the value for 900.546?

Comment: @user3 That construct with the `flag` variable does exactly the same as `for/break/else` already does in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Putting an `else` after your `for` loop you were an the right track! When you put an [`else` after a loop](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops), that `else` block is executed each time the loop exits normally, i.e. without using e.g. `break`. Thus, (assuming that your groups are non-overlapping) you just need to add a `break` statement to the end of your `if` block, i.e. after `location.append((distance))`. Then it works as expected.

Also, instead of checking whether the number is in the `range` (which creates and searches a list each time!) you should just use `<=` and `<`. Also, you already have the `value`, so why not use it?

```
for (lower_bound, upper_bound), value in mapping_dict.items():
    if lower_bound <= x < upper_bound:
        location.append(value)
        break
else:
    location.append(len(mapping_dict) + 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I have faced a similar problem once, because I found a small `RangeDict` class:

```
class RangeDict (dict):
    def __init__ (self, *args):
        super ().__init__ ()

    def __setitem__ (self, k, v):
        if not isinstance (k, slice): raise ValueError ('Indices must be slices.')
        super ().__setitem__ ( (k.start, k.stop), v)

    def __getitem__ (self, k):
        for (start, stop), v in self.items ():
            if start <= k < stop: return v
        raise IndexError ('{} out of bounds.'.format (k) )
```

I hope this class wraps your desired funcionality. Obviously lookup is O(N) and not O(1).

Sample usage:

```
r = RangeDict ()
r [0:100] = 1
r [100:400] = 2
r [400:800] = 3

for x in [3.5, 5.4, 300.12, 500.78, 600.45, 900.546]:
    print (r [x] )
#Last value raises IndexError
```

Comment: +1 Neat! Just curious: Any particular reason why you are not using `if start <= k < stop: return v`?

Comment: @tobias_k In order to minimize comparisons.

Comment: Though so, but isn't `x < y < z` like `x < y and y < z`, i.e. won't it stop early, too, if the first conditions is not met?

Comment: @tobias_k Ahh. Good catch. Sure if it is evaluated lazily (and why should it not), it boils down to the same. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Hyperboreus Lazyness of comparison chaining is [documented](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in), as is the fact that the middle expression is evaluated only once.